# Hide specific product from Woocommerce Shop page if the logged-in user has already been purchased

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am creating an LMS using LearnDash + WooCommerce. I am trying to find a way to hide specific product from the Woocommerce product table page. If the logged in user has already purchased said product a) prevent the user from purchasing it twice, and b) so that I can display a product grid for them without the already purchased item(s).

Another example: if a user who purchased Item B and D goes to the shop, Item B and D should not even be displayed for them.

```
+--------+----------+
| Item A |   $116   |
+--------+----------+
| Item B |   $96    |
+--------+----------+        
| Item C |   $41    |
+--------+----------+
| Item D |   $78    |
+--------+----------+

         ↓

+--------+----------+
| Item A |   $116   |
+--------+----------+        
| Item C |   $41    |
+--------+----------+
```

This is my code:

```
/* Avoid buying the same product again in WooCommerce by adding products to the cart by logged-in users before checkout */
function filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation( $passed, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id = null, $variations = null) {
    // Retrieve the current user object
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    // Check for variantions, if you don't want this, delete this code line
    $product_id = $variation_id > 0 ? $variation_id : $product_id;
    
    // Checks if a user (by email or ID or both) has bought an item
    if ( wc_customer_bought_product( $current_user->user_email, $current_user->ID, $product_id ) ) {
        // Display an error message
        wc_add_notice( __( 'You have already enrolled into the course. ' , 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );

        $passed = false;
    }

    return $passed;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 10, 5 );
```

So any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the product query using the `pre_get_posts` action hook and then you can get current user products that they already purchased. pass all products id to `post__not_in`. check the below code. code will go active theme function.php file.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'hide_product_from_shop_page_if_user_already_purchased', 20 );

function hide_product_from_shop_page_if_user_already_purchased( $query ) {
   
    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() ) return;
   
    if ( ! is_admin() && is_shop() ) {

        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        if ( 0 == $current_user->ID ) return;
       
        $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
            'meta_value'  => $current_user->ID,
            'post_type'   => 'shop_order',
            'post_status' => array( 'wc-processing', 'wc-completed' ),
        ) );
       
        if ( ! $customer_orders ) return;
        
        $product_ids = array();
        
        foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) {
            $order = wc_get_order( $customer_order->ID );
            if( $order ){
                $items = $order->get_items();
                foreach ( $items as $item ) {
                    $product_id    = $item->get_product_id();
                    $product_ids[] = $product_id;
                }
            }
        }

        $product_ids = array_unique( $product_ids );

        $query->set( 'post__not_in', $product_ids );
    }

}
```

Comment: hi. the product table is still showing.

Comment: product table? or shop? can you share a link of the site?

Comment: I want to hide a product from the woocoomerce product table as I have mentioned above.